# Python PyQt4: How to pass the combox name to a variable to simplify the script

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have in my tab widget script a class with the name Cuentas. It opens a new MainWindow containing several editable comboboxes. The same happens for almost all the tabs. I need to know the selected combobox name and the current text.

That's what I have:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
        if obj == self.CB_Grupo:
            text = str(self.CB_Grupo.currentText())
        if obj == self.CB_Nombre:
            text = str(self.CB_Nombre.currentText())
        if obj == self.CB_Banco:
            text = str(self.CB_Banco.currentText())
        print text
        cb_name = obj.objectName()
        cb_name = str(cb_name)
        print cb_name
```

It works.
To make that shorter, I tried to use a variable for the combobox name

```
        cb_text = str(self.cb_name.currentText())          
    return super(Cuentas, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

I get this error: AttributeError: 'Cuentas' object has no attribute 'cb_name'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your code **self.** cb_name you are indicating that cb_name is an attribute of the class, but it is not, it is a string that represents the objectName of some of the elements, what you must do if you want to reduce the code is the next:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn and obj in (self.CB_Grupo, self.CB_Nombre, self.CB_Banco):
        cb_text = str(obj.currentText())
        print(cb_text)
    return super(Cuentas, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```